# pyplot histogram, different color for each bar (bin)

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I would like to have a different color for each bar in pyplot histogram.

**FROM THIS**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '20'

data = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
plt.hist(data);
```

[image]

**TO THIS**:

[image]

Comment: You could try [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):  `import seaborn as sns` and `sns.countplot(x=data, palette=['r', 'g', 'b'])`.

Comment: See also [Have each histogram bin with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085926/have-each-histogram-bin-with-a-different-color)

Comment: seabirn option looks great in the answer, that you suggest is also good. Somehow I didn't find them, when I was searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to use `pyplot.bar` instead of `pyplot.hist`, which has the option `color` for each bin.

The inspiration is from:
https://stackabuse.com/change-font-size-in-matplotlib/

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '20'

data = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']

plt.bar( range(3), Counter(data).values(), color=['red', 'green', 'blue']);
plt.xticks(range(3), Counter(data).keys());
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

According to @JohanC suggestion, there is additional optional using seaborn (It seems me the best option):

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.countplot(x=data, palette=['r', 'g', 'b'])
```

Also, there is a very similar question:

[Have each histogram bin with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69085926/have-each-histogram-bin-with-a-different-color)